# Break python regular expression with escape into multiple lines

Tags: python

I have a python beginner's question.  How would one break this line into multiple lines?

```
SET_CMD = re.compile (r'boot +set-cmd +-s +command\=(?P<pw>.*?)$')
```

I don't want to do this because pep8 complains.

```
SET_CMD = re.compile\
    (r'boot +set-cmd +-s +command\=(?P<pw>.*?)$')
```

Thanks,
Mat

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
SET_CMD = re.compile (r'boot +set-cmd +-s'
                      r' +command\=(?P<pw>.*?)$')
```

There are two key facts here:

- being inside of parentheses provides implicit line continuation
- consecutive strings are automatically concatenated

Answer (score 1):

Instead of breaking before the parantheses, you could use the [regex verbosity flag](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE) to split the expression in multiple lines. Additionally you can include comments, which might come handy for complicated expressions.

For your example:

```
SET_CMD = re.compile(r'''boot\s        # Comment
                         +set-cmd\s    # ...
                         +-s\s
                         +command
                         \=(?P<pw>.*?)$')''', re.VERBOSE)
```

Note that I inserted some `\s` to match whitespaces, since `re.VERBOSE` ignores the whitespaces and linebreaks in the expression.